# PostgreSQL Transform Geometries

Tags: sql, postgresql, geometry

I have a table full of Easting/Northing points that I want to transform into a column in SRID:27700.
I'm using Postgres with postgis installed.

I'm trying this:

```
alter table ua
add column location geometry(point,27700);

UPDATE ua 
    SET "location" = 'SRID=27700;POINT(' || ua."Easting" || ' ' || ua."Northing" || ')';
```

Of course this returns the locations in easting/northing, but when I try to first transform the points using ST_Transform, it returns

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function st_transform(character varying, integer) does not exist

I don't know how to get beyond this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ST_Transform gets one of these set of params and none of them gets character as the first param type whereas you are passing character as first param and int as second param!

```
geometry ST_Transform(geometry g1, integer srid);
geometry ST_Transform(geometry geom, text to_proj);
geometry ST_Transform(geometry geom, text from_proj, text to_proj);
geometry ST_Transform(geometry geom, text from_proj, integer to_srid);
```

I think this should work :

```
update ua 
set "east/north" = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || ua."Easting" ||' '|| ua."Northing" || ')',27700)
```

Comment: Okay, so I'm trying to put both values into a new geometry column like this `update ua set "east/north" = (ST_GeomFromText('POINT('ua."Easting" || ua."Northing"')',27700))` and it then says my table doesn't exist. I'm sure it's something to do with syntax but it's beyond me. Thank you for your help!

Comment: your code has some minor issue , updated my answer, hopefully that works